# Yesod devel server only listening on ipv6

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm running "cabal install && yesod devel" using yesod 0.9.2.2 but it is only listening using ipv6.  Does anyone know how to configure it to listen on ipv4 as well?  I'm running it on Windows 7.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try just browsing to ``localhost``? I have used ``yesod devel`` many times and it just worked, and there's nothing special about my computer.

Comment: Well that does work if I'm just on localhost but our network here does not have ipv6 enabled so remote computers cannot browse to my site.  Looking at netstat I can see that it is only listening on my ipv6 address and not ipv4

Comment: @Caleb: The development server is designed to be used locally. Have you checked if this also happens with the production server? (Do `cabal configure -fproduction`).

Comment: Personally I would consider this a feature...ipv4 should have died by now.

Comment: Yeah, I did build it for production it's still only listening on ipv6.   @Dan - Agreed, but unfortunately this is the world we live in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symptom you describe have so far been observed on BSD and Debian, but it looks like Windows is also affected.

It is a known problem with Yesod, or actually with Wasp, or, to be precise, with the network library. One place to follow up on this issue is [this githup issue](https://github.com/snoyberg/warp/issues/9) or the [current discussion on haskell-lists](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-September/095491.html), which was partly caused by your question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep my eye on those.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't currently have a similar setup to test this, you will probably find that if something is listening to IPv6 port X, and there is nothing listening on the same port X for IPv4, then the IPv6 port will receive the connection. The IPv6 server will see a connection coming from "IPv6" address ::ffff:1.2.3.4 (this is called an IPv4 Mapped IPv6 address). The kernel provides the translation between the IPv6 and IPv4 endpoints. IPv4 is used over the wire.

I don't know about Windows 7, but some systems (eg. *some* Linux distributions) will by default disable this feature by setting a particular sysctl, which would mean that the server would need to bind to separate IPv4 and IPv6 sockets (which is, in my experience, the preferable option). Applications are free to override this default behaviour.