# How to fix the yesod ipv6 only issue?

Tags: haskell, yesod

There's an [outstanding issue with yesod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486257/yesod-devel-server-only-listening-on-ipv6) where it only listens on ipv6.
I am following the yesod in five minutes guide and have this issue when running "yesod devel".  How can I fix it for now and get up and running to try the framework out?  I tried editing the myapp/dist/devel.hs to use Warp's runSettings with an ipv4 address set instead of the default run, but running "yesod devel" again just over wrote the myapp/dist/devel.hs file.

Comment: Which version of the network package are you using? There was supposed to be a new release that addressed the problem.

Comment: Hmm... then I don't know what to say. Can you send an email to the cafe explaining which OS and version of GHC you're running?

Comment: Sure.  But in the mean time is there somewhere I can edit whatever is generating dist/devel.hs to generate code using runSettings instead of run?

Comment: If you unpack the `yesod` package, the devel.hs file is generated by `Devel.hs`. You're interested in line 162.

Answer (score 1):

On my freebsd box, i just run `#sysctl -w net.inet6.ip6.v6only=0`, then it works !